# Oracle DBMS_SCHEDULER.DROP_JOB fails to drop a job

Tags: oracle11g, jobs

In Oracle 11g, I am trying to drop a job; but, it gives me the below error:

```
SQL> exec DBMS_SCHEDULER.DROP_JOB(job_name => "MyCaseSensitiveJobName");
BEGIN DBMS_SCHEDULER.DROP_JOB(job_name => "MyCaseSensitiveJobName"); END;

                                           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 44:
PLS-00905: object Job_Owner.MyCaseSensitiveJobName is invalid
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, I found my mistake!

The below execution was successful:

```
SQL> exec DBMS_SCHEDULER.DROP_JOB(job_name => '"MyCaseSensitiveJobName"');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

i.e. I should have wrapped the double-quoted job name in single qoutes!